# Intellij Elixir - auto complete is not working

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, elixir

I’m using IntelliJ Community version 2022.2.2 on Windows 11, I also have the Elixir plugin installed (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7522-elixir)

But when I try an auto-complete for a native module like Enum, String and so on I get a “No suggestions” message like this:
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `File` -> `Project Structure`
2. Check the `Project` tab and then you have `SDK`, make sure you point to correct one
3. Again in the `Project` tab go to `Modules`, and then `Dependencies`. Here again check the `Module SDK` whether it points to the correct location